# How do I blur an iframe like I blur an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Is there a way to blur an iframe for a few seconds using jQuery? It should look something like a gaussian blur, for example in photoshop. (here's an [example image](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6juvuzoQ21ruwcwwo1_500.jpg), see the right side)

The link being displayed in the iframe is NOT of the same origin, which is why I have been struggling with this. It's not possible to modify the iframe's contents.

Is it possible to apply a blur to an iframe of a different origin only for a few seconds using jQuery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qmp50z6g/ is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply a blur filter via CSS3:

```
$("iframe").css("filter","blur(5px)")
```

Don't forget to polyfill the filter attribute. Maybe you can consider to apply a class to the iframe with the appropiate properties as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/setufequku/1/)

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this? o_O

Comment: @bjb568 In my original post I explained I only needed it to blur for a few seconds and asked for an answer incorporating jquery.

Comment: Oh, if you specifically needed a jQuery solution you should have made it clear in the question body. I have edited it for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can blur any element in CSS 3:

```css
#iframe-container {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div id="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You know I tried this before and it didn't work? Probably did something wrong, your code seems to be working flawlessly :) Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score -4):

```
iframe.contents().find('body').blur()
```

Comment: this only works if the iframe is displaying content of the same origin, which, as I stated, is not the case

Comment: Blur as in Gaussian blur. Not as in unfocus. -1 because you did not even read the second sentence.